# Error when running UIMA example in Ecplise

Tags: eclipse, uima

I have followed [these Instructions](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.0/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.ovv.eclipse_setup.install_eclipse) on how to setup UIMA in Eclipse. But when imported UIMA example, I got this error.

```
    The project was not built due to "Could not write file: C:\Program Files\apache-uima\examples\bin.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have UAC (User Account Control) activated and the UIMA/Eclipse process cannot write to C:\Program Files. Try placing the UIMA stuff somewhere in your home directory.